# creating a set of paths using raphael js and animate together

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, raphael

I have a gauge pointer that I need to add an arrow at the end, I was able to do it, the only problem is not a set and when the pointer is rotating my arrow is not following its position any ideas guys I know this is a newbie question.

This is the script

```
    $(function(){
        var r = Raphael("gauge", 200, 200);
        var g = r.gauge(0, 180);

        g.bg(r.circle(100, 100, 100).attr({fill:'','stroke-width': '0'}), [100, 100]);

        g.pointer(r.rect(0, 0, 90, 8).attr({fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': '0'}), [90, 4]);

        g.arrow(r.path('M 15,20 0,10 15,0 z').attr({fill: '#fff', 'stroke-width': '0'}).translate(0, 90), [0, 20]);



        setInterval(function(){
            var percent = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
            g.move(percent);
        }, 3000);
    });
```

and you can preview it here http://jsfiddle.net/creativestudio/VH3fR/10/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the working fiddle (Quick Fix): http://jsfiddle.net/VH3fR/13/

I don't know if this is the best solution, What I did is instead of creating a path & translating it, I have created the path directly at the required position.

The reason for the behavior is if you look at the source code of the `move` method, it takes the pointer & applies transform method for rotation on the pointer, which overrides the translate method you called.

#### Alternative Solution

http://jsfiddle.net/VH3fR/14/

Here I removed the rectangle & directly built an arrow using path.

Comment: Another +1 for the alternative.